# $3A$ and $4A$ are supplementary angles...

Tags: trigonometry

If $3A$ and $4A$ are supplementary angles,then find the exact value of :

> $4\cos A - \sec 2A$

I tried breaking the angles into $ A + 2A + 4A$ and then using the formulas for angles of a triangle. But, that is not helping. What is the correct approach?

Comment: What does mean *supplementary angles* ?

Comment: Two angles are supplementary if their sum is $\pi$

Comment: Thanks ! Did you use it somehow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $3A+4A=\pi,$

$\cos2A=\cdots=-\cos5A$ and $\sin6A=\sin A$

$$\implies\cos A+\cos3A+\cos5A=\dfrac{\sin2A+\sin4A-\sin2A+\sin6A-\sin4A}{2\sin A}=\dfrac12$$

$$\implies \cos A+\cos3A=\dfrac12-\cos5A=\dfrac12+\cos2A$$

$$4\cos A-\sec2A=\dfrac{4\cos A\cos2A-1}{\cos2A}=\dfrac{2(\cos A+\cos3A)-1}{\cos2A}=?$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT.
If $3A$ and $4A$ are supplementary, then $\sin 3A=\sin 4A$. By expanding this you can find a relation for $\cos A$, which will allow you to show that $4\cos A-\sec 2A=2$.